# A formula in this worksheet contains one or more invalid references error

Tags: excel, charts, vba

I am using same code many times with few changes in row numbers to create charts of same type. But the following msg box pops up on the sheet where charts are plotted.

"A formula in this worksheet contains one or more invalid references. Verify that your formula contain a valid path, workbook, range name, and cell reference."

How to get rid of this message box? I tried  using

```
 Application.DisplayAlertS = False
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Quick way to find all invalid references: F5 -> Special, select "Formulas" then check "Errors" only. If it selects multiple cells change their background to Red, then fix all of them one by one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going to need to find the formula and either alter the link or break it, nine times out of ten, you'll have a cell reference going to a sheet or a work book that no longer exists (or isn't open), this will occur more if you're using `.delete` in your script

Unfortunately, Excel does not make it easy to find this link, you can look in the data tab and see existing connections, then break them. But previous experience has not had this work all the time.

You can also try [this macro from Allen Wyatt](https://excelribbon.tips.net/T008664_Tracking_Down_Invalid_References.html), which will check your sheets and create a new sheet with a list of potential errors *formula errors*.

```vba
Sub CheckReferences()
' Check for possible missing or erroneous links in
' formulas and list possible errors in a summary sheet

  Dim iSh As Integer
  Dim sShName As String
  Dim sht As Worksheet
  Dim c, sChar As String
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
  Dim wks As Worksheet
  Dim sChr As String, addr As String
  Dim sFormula As String, scVal As String
  Dim lNewRow As Long
  Dim vHeaders

  vHeaders = Array("Sheet Name", "Cell", "Cell Value", "Formula")
  'check if 'Summary' worksheet is in workbook
  'and if so, delete it
  With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
  End With

  For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
    If Worksheets(i).Name = "Summary" Then
      Worksheets(i).Delete
    End If
  Next i

  iSh = Worksheets.Count

  'create a new summary sheet
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(iSh)
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = "Summary"
  With Sheets("Summary")
    Range("A1:D1") = vHeaders
  End With
  lNewRow = 2

  ' this will not work if the sheet is protected,
  ' assume that sheet should not be changed; so ignore it
  On Error Resume Next

  For i = 1 To iSh
    sShName = Worksheets(i).Name
    Application.Goto Sheets(sShName).Cells(1, 1)
    Set rng = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 23)

    For Each c In rng
      addr = c.Address
      sFormula = c.Formula
      scVal = c.Text

      For j = 1 To Len(c.Formula)
        sChr = Mid(c.Formula, j, 1)

        If sChr = "[" Or sChr = "!" Or _
          IsError(c) Then
          'write values to summary sheet
          With Sheets("Summary")
            .Cells(lNewRow, 1) = sShName
            .Cells(lNewRow, 2) = addr
            .Cells(lNewRow, 3) = scVal
            .Cells(lNewRow, 4) = "'" & sFormula
          End With
          lNewRow = lNewRow + 1
          Exit For
        End If
      Next j
    Next c
  Next i

' housekeeping
  With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
  End With

' tidy up
  Sheets("Summary").Select
  Columns("A:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit
  Range("A1:D1").Font.Bold = True
  Range("A2").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @Jake. I am going to try this. Meanwhile, can you help me with another question http://bit.ly/1J9ndmu (I am looking for the solution of the second part - the legend part)

Answer (score 2):

I was searching because I had the same problem with empty charts and pop up message with the same error. As nobody here had any solution for this problem and I discovered one that solved it, I'm here to share the solution for this problem in my case.

I simplified all the named ranges' formulas, example:

```
Named range = Offset(Plan1!A1;0;0;8-CountBlank(Other named range))
```

I put the last part `"8-CountBlank(Other named range)"` to be calculated in a Worksheet and replaced this in the formula for the range with the result. No more pop up errors were displayed if the chart were totally empty. I hope to would help someone someday with the same problem.

Comment: references in charts are also able to create this error, you have go through the data and see where you see `#REF`

Answer (score -1):

The accepted solution didn't work for me but I could immediately solve using this free Excel Addin

Just download and follow the instructions here: 
http://www.manville.org.uk/software/findlink.htm

[image]

[image]